# How can I check whether is answer's author the same as qustion's author?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table structure:

```
// QandA
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+
| id | type | author_id |       title       |            content            | question_id |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+
| 1  | 0    | 10        | title of question | content of question           | NULL        |
| 2  | 1    | 33        | NULL              | content of answer             | 1           |
| 3  | 0    | 51        | title of question | content of question           | NULL        |
| 4  | 1    | 10        | NULL              | content of answer             | 1           |
| 5  | 1    | 23        | NULL              | content of answer             | 3           |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+

-- type column: 0 is question, 1 is answer
-- title column: it is always NULL for answers
-- question_id column: it is NULL for questions and the id of its own question for answers
```

I want to set a blue background color if the `author_id` is the author of question. Something like this:

[image]

So All I'm trying to do is detecting whether is answer's author the same as question's author? How can I do that?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT id, (author_id = {Id don't know}) AS set_highlight
FROM QandQ
WHERE id = :id OR question_id = :id
ORDER BY type ASC, id ASC
```

---

This is expected result for `$id = 1`:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | set_highlight |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | 1             |
| 2  | 0             |
| 4  | 1             |
+----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,it is not complete expected result.It is just way for your need.

```
   select answer.*,question.* from(select * from yourtable where `type`=1)answer
    inner join 
    (select * from yourtable where `type`=0)question on question.id=answer.question_id and answer.author_id=question.author_id
WHERE question.id = :id OR answer.question_id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
SELECT id, 
    (CASE WHEN author_id = (
            SELECT author_id 
            FROM QandA
            WHERE id = :id
                AND type = 0) 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) AS set_highlight
FROM QandA
WHERE id = :id OR question_id = :id
ORDER BY type ASC, id ASC;
```